# create dtype array column in dataframe

Tags: pandas

How to create 'col new' in dataframe ?

```
          'col 1'   'col 2'   'col new'
0           a         b         [a, b]
1           c         d         [c, d]
2           e         f         [e, f]
```

Thank in advance

Comment: what is your question? do you want dtype or concat both fields.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension` with convert values to `list` from `tuple`s:

```
df['col new'] = [list(x) for x in zip(df['col 1'],df['col 2'])]

print (df)
  col 1 col 2 col new
0     a     b  [a, b]
1     c     d  [c, d]
2     e     f  [e, f]

print (type(df.loc[0, 'col new']))
<class 'list'>
```

Another solution with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['col new'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['col 1'], x['col 2']], axis=1)
print (df)
  col 1 col 2 col new
0     a     b  [a, b]
1     c     d  [c, d]
2     e     f  [e, f]

print (type(df.loc[0, 'col new']))
<class 'list'>
```

---

If need `numpy array`s:

```
df['col new'] = [np.array(x) for x in zip(df['col 1'],df['col 2'])]

print (type(df.loc[0, 'col new']))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simpler way

```
In [216]: df['col new'] = df[['col 1', 'col 2']].values.tolist()

In [217]: df
Out[217]:
  col 1 col 2 col new
0     a     b  [a, b]
1     c     d  [c, d]
2     e     f  [e, f]
```

Comment: if col 1 and col 2 are datetime type, not working (it changes type). In other types it seems to work.